Bad performances seems due to spanner thread pool
I've a simple crud service, on a kubernetes cluster talking with Spanner.
The service serves gRPC requests using grpc-api:1.61.1 ServerBuilder object.
I built it using a newFixedThreadPool.
There is no much business logic, the service simply serves

a pure get by id (indexed)
In case of entity found, an update by primary key
In case of entity not found, an insert

To talk with Spanner I'm using a SpannerObption builder.
I have around 7k queries per second (5k Read, 2k write).
I have 30 clients that talk with 20 server.
From my metrics I can see that Spanner itself is performing pretty well: no more than 20ms per read, no more that 50ms per write, more or less.
The server, calling with the very same number of requests an endpoint THAT DOESN'T use Spanner but has a random delay from 20 to 50 ms, it's able to serve all the requests in a reasonable amount of time (not to much latency).
Calling instead the endpoints as described above, the latency of the requests dramatically decrease. We are talking on 6/7 seconds for the client call. Also, metrics done using an interceptor server side (so, from startCall to close) are in line with the client metrics (seconds). Spanner, instead continue performing well, and also the RPC method is performing well (I've a metric also at that level).
My doubt is related to a sort of collision using kotlin, gRPC server thread pool and Spanner thread pool (that looking down in the code is a Scheduled thread pool).
Is it something known? There is some best practice to follow to achieve the expected performances by a gRPC server?
